# Cordova webview which is pointing to external site is not loading images

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I have developed a website hosted in Apache (say xxx.com) which is working fine in all desktop/mobile browsers. It has few images which is hosted in self (xxx.com) and few images comes from other sites (yyy.com).

I created an Android App using Cordova which points to xxx.com. Deleted everything from Cordova_app/www folder. It works all fine, images (HTML img src) from self (xxx.com) loads fine but images from other domains (yyy.com) are not loading. What is the reason for images not to load from other domains?

Any help would be great

Below is the config.xml details

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.xxx" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>xxx</name>

    <content src="https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxx.com" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />

    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <platform name="android">a
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="^5.2.2" />
</widget>
```

Comment: how u resolved this issue ? images are loading from https but still image not loading

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I figured out the issue. Images from other domain was being called thru http not https. Since xxx.com is running in https, desktop and mobile browsers don't complain about it. But Webview blocks the content. "The content must be served over HTTPS".